# Python Multithreading: time.sleep() is not having effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have to put a time delay in my python multithread code. I have tried with time.sleep(), but it seems, time.sleep is not having any effect. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to add a delay in the thread (without any event-driven logic)? Below is the code behaving in the same manner where first thread supposed to run and at the end, it is having a 3-second delay, then the second thread starts and at the end waits for 3 seconds.

```
import threading 
import time
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)

def print_hi(): 
    print("Hi") 
    time.sleep(3)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)  

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the application to take the wait into account, you need to make it wait for the `t1` thread to end before it starts the `t2` thread starts, try the following code:

```
import threading 
import time
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)

def print_hi(): 
    print("Hi") 
    time.sleep(3)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)  

t1.start()
t1.join()
t2.start()
t2.join()
```

The `t1.join()` will make sure that the `t1` thread is complete before starting the `t2` thread.

Comment: worked. Thanks. But I can not use with opencv video capture. The frame is just freezing for that time and again takes another frame and so on. Do you know How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the first thread, wait 3 seconds, and start the second one, just put the time.sleep() between `t1.start()` and `t2.start()`.

If you want to start the first thread, wait for it to finish (with a pause of 3 seconds in the first tread), and then start the second one, put a `t1.join()` between `t1.start()` and `t2.start()`, to wait for the first thread to end before starting the second one.